# How to convert iso date into string type like this dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Tags: datetime-format

I need to convert iso date into string format like this

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

2016-05-31T01:12:56.134Z->dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: You can use moment.js to format a time string any way you would want to. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: How do we even know he is using JavaScript?

Comment: formatted the code